# Is the transition semigroup of the solution of an SDE with Lipschitz coefficients strongly continuous on $C_b$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $b,\sigma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous (and hence at most of linear growth) and $$Lf:=bf'+\frac12\sigma^2f''\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$$
- $W$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $(X^x_t)_{(t,\:x)\in[0,\:\infty)\times\mathbb R}$ be a continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X_t^x=x+\int_0^tb(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag1$$ and $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ for any bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $t\ge0$

> If $f\in C_b(\mathbb R)$, are we able to conclude $\left\|\kappa_tf-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0$?

Assume first that $f\in C^2_b$. Fix $(t,x)$. Since $f'$ is bounded, $$(\kappa_tf)(x)=f(x)+\text E\left[\int_0^t(Lf)(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}s\right].\tag2$$ The crucial question seems to be whether we're allowed to apply Fubini's theorem to the second term on the rhs. By Jensen's inequality, $$\text E\left[\sup_{s\le t}|X^x_s|\right]^2\le\text E\left[\sup_{s\le t}|X^x_s|^2\right]<\infty\tag3$$ (where the finiteness of the rhs follows from the Lipschitz assumption) and by the linear growth assumption for some $$\text E\left[\int_0^t|(Lf)(X^x_s)|\:{\rm d}s\right]\le ct\left(1+\text E\left[\sup_{s\le t}|X^x_s|\right]\right)\left\|f'\right\|_\infty+\frac c2t\left(1+\text E\left[\sup_{s\le t}|X^x_s|^2\right]\right)\left\|f''\right\|_\infty<\infty\tag4$$ for some $c\ge0$. So, we should be able to apply Fubini's theorem and obtain $$(\kappa_tf)(x)=f(x)+\int_0^t(\kappa_s(Lf))(x)\:{\rm d}s.\tag5$$ So, we should have $$|(\kappa_tf)(x)-f(x)|\le t\left\|Lf\right\|_\infty.\tag6$$ The only problem is that $Lf$ might be unbounded. So, I guess we need to assume $f\in C_c^2(\mathbb R)$ (since I don't see that a larger class ensures that $Lf$ is bounded).

> This allows us to conclude the claim for such a $f$ and, by density, for $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$. Is it possible to extend the result to $f\in C_b(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the convergence does, in general, not hold true for bounded continuous functions. Strong continuity on $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a pretty strong assumption on a Markov semigroup.

**Example:** For fixed $b \neq 0$ consider the semigroup $$\kappa_t f(x) := f(x+bt)$$ associated with the deterministic process $X_t := bt$. Clearly, $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies the SDE $$dX_t  = b \, dt.$$ Since $$\kappa_t f(x)-f(x) = f(x+bt)-f(x)$$ it follows that $$\|\kappa_t f-f\|_{\infty} \xrightarrow[]{t \to 0} 0 \iff \text{$f$ is uniformly continuous}.$$ So, if we pick some bounded continuous function $f$ which fails to be uniformly continuous, then $\|\kappa_t f-f\|_{\infty}$ fails to converge to $0$ as $t \to 0$.

**Remark:** It is possible to show that the semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t \geq 0}$ associated with the one-dimensional Brownian motion fails to be strongly continuous on $C_b(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. there exists $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|\kappa_t f-f\|_{\infty}$ does not converge to $0$ as $t \to 0$; see e.g. Example 1.7(d) in *Lévy Matters III* by Böttcher & Schilling & Wang for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just two further questions: (a) We should at least be able to conclude that the orbits are uniformly continuous for all $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $Lf$ is bounded, or did I make any mistake in my reasoning? (b) If $f\in C_b^2(\mathbb R)$, $(\kappa_s|Lf|)(x)<\infty$ for all $s\ge0$ and hence $(5)$ is well-defined. So, we should be able to conclude that $C_b^2$ is contained in the "weak generator" of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ (considered as a semigroup on $C_b^2$), right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) I don't see a mistake in your reasoning. (b) Yeah, I suppose; at least if you mean by "weak generator" that the limit exists pointwise.

Comment: (a) (I've meant $f\in C^2_b$, not $f\in C^2$.) (b) Yes, that's what I mean. If we consider $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ as a semigroup on $C_0(\mathbb R)$, is there any chance to fully characterize the domain of the generator? I know that it contains $C_c^2(\mathbb R)$, but I would like to show that it equals $\left\{f\in C_0\cap C^2(\mathbb R):Lf\in C_0(\mathbb R)\right\}$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Certainly not. Already for Brownian motion it's difficult enough to describe the domain of the generator (as far as I know an open question for dimension $d \geq 3$).

Comment: I'm asking because it seems like this is the conclusion of Chapter 8, Theorem 2.1 of Ethier/Kurtz. (At least if we assume that $\sigma\in C^2(\mathbb R)$, $\sigma(\mathbb R)\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ and $\sigma''$ is bounded).

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't have a copy of the book right now. To come back to the example from my previous comment: It is possible to show that in dimension $d=3$ there is a function $f \in C_0$ which is in the domain of the generator of 3-dim. Brownian motion but which is not twice differentiable. Since "your" operator $L$ satisfies $D(L) \subseteq C^2$ this means that domain of $L$ is too small ... we cannot use $L$ to fully describe the infinitesimal generator. (Since you are considering $d=1$ this might be different but I wouldn't expect it to be true; perhaps I'm wrong.)

Comment: You can find the theorem here: https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA373&lpg=PA373&dq=%22DEGENERATE+DIFFUSIONS%22+%22ethier%22+%22Lipschitz+continuous%22&source=bl&ots=7axNtWT1yC&sig=ACfU3U3SD_KUW7FwXqzLYH0SB_ERegy1Vw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi72uqD16LgAhURi8MKHQMaAcAQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22DEGENERATE%20DIFFUSIONS%22%20%22ethier%22%20%22Lipschitz%20continuous%22&f=false

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't see how this is exactly related to the statement from your earlier comment. Since the result in Ethier-Kurtz holds for any $d \geq 1$, it cannot imply your assertion, as I just explained in my previous comment.

Comment: In Corollary 1.2, they claim that $\mathcal D(B):=\left\{f\in C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C^2(\mathbb R):Lf\in C_0(\mathbb R)\right\}$, $Bf:=Lf$ for $f\in\mathcal D(B)$, generates a Feller semigroup on $C_0(\mathbb R)$ (they don't claim that this is true in higher dimension). Since the generator uniquely determines the semigroup, my assertion should follow. What am I missing? (BTW, even Theorem 2.1 is only given for $d=1$.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d Your link pointed me to Theorem 2.5, not Theorem 2.1. If it's saying this, then what exactly is your question? As I said, I didn't expect it to be true but obviously this doesn't mean that it can't be true...

Comment: I thought you might know a simpler proof in the special case of the question (the Theorem in Ethier/Kurtz is more general).

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, I don't; I didn't even know that these kind of results for one-dimensional SDEs.

Comment: By the result of [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280211/weak-generator-of-feller-semigroup), the weak generator and the generator coincide. By (b) from my first comment, $C_b^2(\mathbb R)$ is contained in the weak generator, hence in the generator. This seems to be wrong, doesn't it (especially in light of the formerly discussed result by Ethier/Kurtz)? What am I missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d In the linked question I'm considering the generator as a mapping $A: D(A) \to C_0(\mathbb{R})$ where $D(A) \subseteq C_0(\mathbb{R})$; in particular we cannot conclude that $C_b^2(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in the domain of the generator as the functions fail, in general, to vanish at infinity.

Comment: Sure, but we would still obtain that $C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C_b^2(\mathbb R)$ is in the domain of the generator. Unless $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C_b^2(\mathbb R)$ implies $Lf\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ (which it doesn't, if I'm not mistaken), this is in contradiction to the mentioned result.

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, we obtain that $$\{f \in C_0 \cap C_b^2; Lf \in C_0\}$$ is contained in the domain. In order to apply the result from my question, you need to know that $Lf \in C_0$. The statement is saying that  if$f \in C_0$ is such that the pointwise limit $Lf$ exists **and** $Lf \in C_0$, then $f$ is in the domain of the generator.

Comment: Ah, perfect. That was the point I was missing. Thank you. The only puzzle piece that's missing now, is how we can show that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is a core of $(\mathcal D(A),A)$. If that's more involved, I would ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Opening a new question sounds like a good idea; as far as I can see it's not exactly obvious.

Comment: Done: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101141/47771

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see; I will take a look lateron.

Comment: I've still got some problems with the [carré du champ operator question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3102774/47771). If $f\in L^2(\mu)$, $\kappa_tf$ is defined in terms of the unique contractive linear extension of $\kappa_t:(\mathcal M_b(E,\mathcal E),\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\mu)})\to L^2(\mu)$. Strictly speaking, we only know that there is a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $(\kappa_tf)(x)=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)$ for all $x\in E\setminus N$ (since the right-hand side is only well-defined outside $N$).

Comment: I've still got some problems with the [carré du champ operator question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3102774/47771). The actual question (how we can prove the inequality $(2)$) is still unanswered.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'm sorry that you still have problems with this question. As you might imagine, I do have a life somewhere outside stackexchange and in particular I do have some other things on my mind than answering your questions. So please don't expect me to a) answer all your (numerous) questions and b) do not hurry me.

Comment: In the special case $b=-2^{-1}h'$ for some $h\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ and $\sigma=1$, are we able to conclude regularity in space of $\kappa_tf$ from regularity of $f$? e.g. if $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, is $\kappa_tf\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ (or at least differentiable at all)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d We cannot expect that $\kappa_t f$ has compact support; as you can see, for instance, from the particular case that $(X_t)_t$ is a Brownian motion. To prove the differentiability you can use Girsanov's theorem, I guess.

Comment: I've expected an easier argument. For example, how is $(2)$ on page 4 proven [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022123602000289/1-s2.0-S0022123602000289-main.pdf?_tid=06b3cdf6-4683-4f09-91de-6011fb90354e&acdnat=1549705131_65830e710f1674e2adeffcce9b3d709e)? (I don't get why $\kappa_tf$ is in the domain of $\Gamma$ at all)

Comment: @0xbadf00d In a research paper an application of Girsanov's theorem counts as "easy argument". Might well be that there is an easier argument, it wast just an idea. Anyway, I'm not familiar with functional inequalities... so if you are stuck with this paper, then it would probably a good idea to take a look at books on this topic (which usually provide somewhat more detailed proofs/arguments than research papers).

Comment: Okay, last question, I promise. I think I've made a mistake in reasoning. We don't need that $\kappa_tf$ is differentiable, we only need that $\kappa_tf\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $(\kappa_tf)^2\in\mathcal D(A)$, where $\mathcal D(A)$ denotes the domain of the $C_0(\mathbb R)$-generator. It's a general fact (for any semigroup of operators) that $\kappa_tf\in\mathcal D(A)$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$. What about $(\kappa_tf)^2\in\mathcal D(A)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well, you can try to apply the criterion by Ethier & Kurtz to prove that $(\kappa_t f)^2 \in D(A)$.... see one of the many comments from above. As far as I can see, you will need that $(\kappa_t f)'' \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ ...which should be true automatically since $\kappa_t f \in D(A)$.

Comment: Don't know which criterion you mean. Do you mean the characterization of $\mathcal D(A)$ that they give?

Comment: @0xbadf00d So call it "characterization" and not "criterion"....

Comment: Just thought you might had something else in mind.