# Show that $C_c^∞(\mathbb R)$ is a core of the generator of the Feller semigroup induced by the strong solution of an SDE with Lipschitz coefficients

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $b,\sigma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous and $$Lf:=bf'+\frac12\sigma^2f''\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$$
- $W$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $(X^x_t)_{(t,\:x)\in[0,\:\infty)\times\mathbb R}$ be a continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X_t^x=x+\int_0^tb(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag1$$ and $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R\tag2$$ for any bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $t\ge0$

> Via $(2)$, $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $C_0(\mathbb R)$. Let $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denote the generator of that semigroup. [As discussed in the comments of the answer to my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3099038/47771), $$\left\{f\in C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C_b^2(\mathbb R):Lf\in C_0(\mathbb R)\right\}\subseteq\mathcal D(A).\tag3$$
>
> **Question 1**: How can we show that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is a core of $(\mathcal D(A),A)$.
>
> **Question 2**: How can we show that $$\tilde{\mathcal D}(A):=\left\{f\in C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C^2(\mathbb R):Lf\in C_0(\mathbb R)\right\}=\mathcal D(A)\tag4,$$ or at least that the left-hand side is contained in $\mathcal D(A)$?

The result I asked for in the second question *seems to be* (i.e. I'm not sure) a consequence of Theorem 2.1 of Chapter 8 in [*Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316658), at least under the assumption that $\sigma(\mathbb R)\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ and $\sigma\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $\sigma''$ is bounded.